# Relationship Question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\ S\ $ be a non-empty Set, and suppose s$\ \in S $.
Assuming $\ S\ $ is finite, what can we deduce about the relationship between  $\ |\mathcal P(S\ \setminus \{s\} )| $ and $\ | \mathcal P(S)|?$

May I know if the question is looking for $\ |\mathcal P(S\ \setminus \{s\} )| =$ $\ | \mathcal P(S)| \over  | \mathcal P(\{s\})| $ ?

Anyone care to elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: What is $\mathcal{P}$?

Comment: $\ \mathcal P(S) $ is powerset of S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$P_1 = \{ A \subset S \mid s \in A\}$$ and $$P_2 = \{ A \subset S \mid s \notin A \}.$$ Then $\mathcal{P}(S) = P_1 \uplus P_2$ and $\mathcal{P}(S\setminus\{s\}) = P_2$. However, $|P_1| = |P_2|$ by bijection $f : \mathcal{P}(S) \to \mathcal{P}(S)$ (observe that $f$ is its own inverse, that is $f \circ f = \mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{P}(S)}$):

$$f(A) = \begin{cases} A \cup \{s\} & \text{ for } s \notin A \\
A \setminus \{s\} & \text{ for } s \in A \end{cases}$$

So $|\mathcal{P}(S)| = |P_1| + |P_2| = 2 |P_2| = 2|\mathcal{P}(S \setminus\{s\})|$.

I hope this helps ;-)

Comment: Thanks. So how did you derive $\ |\mathcal{P}(S)| = |P_1| + |P_2| = 2 |P_2| = 2|\mathcal{P}(S \setminus\{s\})| \;and \;|P_1| = |P_2| $?

Comment: @Ray.R.Chua I've taken care of a big majority of details, why don't you work out the rest yourself?

Comment: I think I get it. $\ |P_1| = |P_2| $ because f is 1-1 and onto. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

$|\mathcal P(S \setminus \{s\} )| =\frac { | \mathcal P(S)|}{2}$